# Flow - Cannot Get Records by PersonMobilePhone

Tags: visual-workflow, person-accounts

I am working on an auto triggered flow that runs when I create / update an Account. I am trying to get all Account records with the same mobile number as my triggering record, but when I try to filter the records by `PersonMobilePhone`, it does not appear as an option:

[image]

Comment: is the field (Shield) encrypted?

Comment: @cropredy No, no encryption. It is a default field on the Account object.